# How to install 'Nocturn': a pre-built binary app in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: software-installation, binary

I have downloaded the Nocturn app pre-built binary from github. In which directory should I put it so I can run it from dock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite as straightforward as I would have liked but it can be done as follows:

**1. Download and install...**

The following one-liner downloads the 64bit binary, places it in `$HOME/bin` and places a link to allow a place in your `$PATH`:

```
mkdir -v $HOME/bin && \
wget https://github.com/k0kubun/Nocturn/releases/download/v1.6.0/Nocturn-linux-x64.zip && \
unzip Nocturn-linux-x64.zip -d $HOME/bin && \
ln -sv $HOME/bin/Nocturn-linux-x64/Nocturn $HOME/bin
```

For `$HOME/bin` to be properly recognised perhaps the easiest way is to reboot, The addition to your `$PATH` is set in `$HOME/.profile` if you are interested to see how it is done in Ubuntu...

**2. Make a few adjustments...**

On Nocturn's startup there is a nasty error message about themes that can be bypassed with the following:

```
sudo sed -i_bak s'#style "murrine-scrollbar"#style "scrollbar"#' \
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/apps/mate-panel.rc
```

And as well on my system the following was required:

```
sudo apt-get install libgconf-2-4
```

**3. Organise a .desktop file...**

I created a *manual* .desktop file by creating the following file and directory structure:

```
mkdir -pv ~/.local/share/applications/ && \
touch ~/.local/share/applications/Nocturn.desktop
```

Open this file and add something like the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=A great Tweet Application
Terminal=false
Name=Nocturn
Exec=Nocturn
Type=Application
Icon=emblem-web
```

The icon choice is up to you but this one looked ok on my system, it can be found in `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/48x48/emblems/emblem-web.png` with several different sizes available there.

Then make the file executable:

```
chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/Nocturn.desktop
```

**4. Add to dock...**

Search for 'Nocturn' in the 'Show Applications' applet (or simply launch it from the Terminal) and when it is launched right click on the icon and select 'Add to Favourites'. Now you are good to go :).

**5. Gratuitous Screenshot...**

This tested fine on my sytem and below is a screenshot showing the opening screen of Nocturn:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It is working beautifully.Where is the icon stored so I can change it?

Comment: @cgiannakisis Good to hear that all is working well! This particular icon is present in several different sizes as part of the Adwaita icons. For example one size is here: `/usr/share/icons/Adwaita/48x48/emblems/emblem-web.png`. You will find a plethora of icons in `/usr/share/icons` and of course you can add your own...